# How to execute a function that's contained in a string?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am working on a Greasemonkey script and I have string (called 
"link_onclick") which I pull from an array containing all the `onclick`s on the page.
A sample of one of these strings would be:

```
function onclick(event) { return fsb8777307('088');}
```

how do I run link_onclick ?

I only need this bit of code here

```
return fsb8777307('088');
```

to execute. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to execute a string, use eval... http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

or

```
var myCode = 'code goes here';
 var myFunction = new Function(myCode);
 myFunction();
```

Which is probably cleaner

To be selective about which parts of the code you'd like to execute you'll want to take the substring after the { and before the }

You could use Regular Expressions or good old indexOf http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp and subString

Comment: +1 , also preferably use the 2nd method, eval is evil after all :)

Comment: As was posted on an answer of mine 2 weeks ago: Please, do not post links to w3schools. Pretty please. For the sake of learning proper HTML and CSS. w3fools.com

Answer (score 0):

You would run that code with:

```
unsafeWindow.fsb8777307('088');
```

But see also, [this page of the Greasemonkey documents](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Generate_Click_Events).